# what is the difference between animation nodes and audio nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, audio, filmic-blender

I just today found out about animation nodes, which is awesome, but there are some links for audionodes, I don't know whether they are both the same or different.

Answer (score 1):

[Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) Node based visual scripting system designed for motion graphics in Blender.

[Audionodes](https://github.com/nomelif/Audionodes) for Audio generation in Blender nodes.